# Use Explicit or Implicit Model Binding on Routes in Laravel Package

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-9, laravel-models, laravel-package

I am migrating some app functionality into a Laravel package. The package includes Models, Controllers and routes. I am using Laravel 9

Everything is working except my Models are not biding to the routes so the models are not being automatically resolved.

```
// Route
Route::get('/medium/{medium}', 
    [\ArtMoi\Http\Controllers\MediumController::class, 'fetch']
)->name("get-medium");
```

Model does not automatically load.   In the controller below `$medium` is `null`. Route worked when part of the app, but fails when included via a package.

```
// MediumController
use ArtMoi\Models\Medium;
...
public function fetch(Request $request, Medium $medium)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $medium);
    return response()->json($medium);
}
```

Everything works if I don't try to automatically load the model

```
// This works but not the desired approach
use ArtMoi\Models\Medium;

public function fetch(Request $request, $id)
{
    $medium = Medium::find($id);
    $this->authorize('view', $medium);
    return response()->json($medium);
}
```

In my package ServiceProvider I provide the routes with

```
public function boot() 
{
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php');
    });
}
```

I tried to explicitly bind the Model and the route by adding the following to a RouteServiceProvider but it has no effect.

```
// RouteServiceProvider.php
use ArtMoi\Models\Medium;
... 
public function boot()
{
    Route::model('medium', Medium::class);   
}
```

This is the first time I've moved resource type routes to a Package and feel like there is something I am missing.  The only difference with the package from the original app is moving models from  `App\Models` to the package namespace of `ArtMoi\Models`.  Models function as expected when performing queries or other functions and the routes have no conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you test this solution? Modify your boot method.

```
    public function boot() 
    {
        Route::group([
             'middleware'=>['bindings'],
             'prefix' => 'api'
             ], function () {
            $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php');
        });
    }
```

That bindings middleware is [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php) and is registered by default in web and api middleware.

Solution found [here](https://gist.github.com/gabbydgab/df35f753586cd1d3d1374b5d5aeed5a4)

I hope this works, I didn't test it.

Comment: Thanks it did work.  I had to use the full class as exampled in my own answer but this go me there.

Comment: Ur welcome and is good to know this, i did was aware of this, frankly never was aware of that default middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Found that I needed to add the SubstitudeBindings middleware to my routes.

Updated my ServiceProvider to load routes with

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings;
...
public function boot() 
{
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => [SubstituteBindings::class]], function () {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php');
    });
}
```